# KendoUI DropDownList Change event not triggered

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, dom, kendo-ui

I'm new to all this, and did research this quite a bit, and apparently don't "get it".
I'm using C#/.NET4.5 MVC4.

I have a drop down list I populated, and when I change the drop down value, I want to trigger an event.. change event I believe (to redirect to a new page with the value of the drop down selection)

Nothing happens (event not triggered).
I tried using the .Events syntax as part of the Kendo code, but I get an error (error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type)

I'm afraid I don't understand the process flow and how to bind the event to the action, in spite of reading a dozen or more posts about this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is what I got in my View (index.cshtml)

`@model IEnumerable<cfcccDb.Models.matrix>`

`<form method="post">`

`@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()`

```
    .Name("scorematrix")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .Value(ViewBag.SelectedMatrix)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px;" })
    .BindTo(@matrixlist)
    )
```

`</form>`

`<script>`

```
$("#scorematrix").kendoDropDownList({

    change: function (e) {
        var value = this.value();
        alert("value = " + value);
    }

})
```

`</script>`

Comment: FYI, I have the closing paren not show in the ddl code, and I have the ";" after the close paren even though not show here, so that is not the problem

Answer (score 4):

With the MVC wrappers, you should do this to bind the change event:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("scorematrix")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .Value(ViewBag.SelectedMatrix)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px;" })
    .BindTo(@matrixlist)
    .Events(e => e.Change("dropdownlist_change")))

<script>
    function dropdownlist_change() {
        //Handle the change event
    }
</script>
```

If you want to bind the change event in JS, you can do this:

```
$("#scorematrix").data("kendoDropDownList").bind("change", function (e) {
    //Handle the change event
});
```